# Strange ReferenceError in React Native app

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, react-native

I'm building my first react-native application. I'm loading data from my SQLite database in a ListView. No matter what I do I keep receiving 'ReferenceError: apartData is not defined'

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymOLE.png)

Bellow is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, ListView } from 'react-native'
import { Images } from '../../Themes'

var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'vhodove.db', createFromLocation: '~db.sqlite3'})

export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      apartData: "",
    };

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT title FROM entrances_entrance INNER JOIN tasks_schedule WHERE assignee_id=1', (tx, results) => {
          var len = results.rows.length;
          if(len > 0) {
            var row = results.rows.item(0);
            this.setState({apartData: row.apartData});
          }
        });
    });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(apartData),
      isApart: true, isHolder: false
    };
  }

  ListViewItemSeparatorLine = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: .5,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Also, is there a better way of retrieving the data?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are selecting `title` column from the table, you need to change `row.apartData` to `row.title`. Please give it a try.

Comment: row.title doesn't work either.

Comment: Same error or something different?

Comment: It is the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.apartData)`

So change this:

```
 this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(apartData),
      isApart: true, isHolder: false
    };
```

to :

```
 this.state = {
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.apartData),
          isApart: true, isHolder: false
        };
```

Comment: This works, thank you, but it doesn't load any data. Do you have an idea why? When I execute the query directly to the db it loads 50 records.

Comment: @MarcipanRebaru, glad my answer worked. for your db related question I can not say anything without looking at database records, but I feel your inner join query have to rewrite. Please go through this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm

Comment: If that didn't help please raise it as a new question.

Comment: I fixed the select, but still not showing anything. Will raise a question now